# how to develop a python wrapper for a C code?

Tags: python

Well given a C code , is there a way that i can use other languages like python to execute the C code . What i am trying to say is , there are soo many modules  which are built using a language , but also offer access via different languages , is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways. Generically, this is often called a [Foreign Function Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface). That Wikipedia page says the following about Python:

> ```
> * The major dynamic languages, such as Python, Perl, Tcl, and Ruby,
> ```
>
> all provide easy access to native code
>   written in C/C++ (or any other
>   language obeying C/C++ calling
>   conventions).
>             o Python additionally provides the Ctypes module [2](http://www.swig.org/), which
>   can load C functions from shared
>   libraries/DLLs on-the-fly and
>   translate simple data types
>   automatically between Python and C
>   semantics. For example:

```
 import ctypes libc = ctypes.CDLL('/lib/libc.so.6' )   # under Linux/Unix
 t = libc.time(None) # equivalent C code: t = time(NULL)
 print t
```

A popular choice that supports many languages is [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)

Comment: i guess SWIG will be a direct approach. but will i have an inadvertent data loss while using the c/c++ code as python module , for example, when i use STLs and try to pass the values to python data types.

Comment: @Rahul: didn't you ask about C? Then, what has the STL to do with it? Anyhow, read about SWIG's support for the STL here: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it's called "extending" in the Python world. The [official documentation is here](http://docs.python.org/extending/). A short excerpt:

> This document describes how to write
>   modules in C or C++ to extend the
>   Python interpreter with new modules.
>   Those modules can define new functions
>   but also new object types and their
>   methods. The document also describes
>   how to embed the Python interpreter in
>   another application, for use as an
>   extension language. Finally, it shows
>   how to compile and link extension
>   modules so that they can be loaded
>   dynamically (at run time) into the
>   interpreter, if the underlying
>   operating system supports this
>   feature.

An even easier way for Python would be using the `ctypes` standard package to run code in DLLs.